# SolR queries on simple index are getting slower as start param is higher

Tags: performance, solr

I'm working on a simple index containing one million docs with 30 fields each.

a q=*:* with a very low start value (0 for instance) takes only a few milliseconds (~1 actually)

the higher the start value is, the slowest SolR gets...

```
start=100000  =>  171 ms
start=500000  =>  844 ms
start=1000000 => 1274 ms
```

I'm a bit surprised by this performance degradation, and I'm afraid since the index is supposed to grow over hundred million documents within a few month.

Maybe did I something wrong in the schema? Or is it a`enter code here` normal behavior, given slicing docs behind the few first hundreds should usually not happen :)

EDIT

Thanks guys for those explanations - I was guessing something like that, however I do prefer be sure that this was not related to the way the schema has been described. So the question solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you make search query to solr, it collect all the matching documents to the query. Then it skip the document until the start value is reached and then return the results.

Other point to note is that, every time you make the same search query but with higher start value, these documents are also not present in cache, so it might refresh cache as well. (depending on the size and type of cache you have configured)

Comment: The cursors will be available in solr 5.3 as the official document from apache solr site. You can find the more information about this here: [Pagination of Results](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results)

Comment: @gdelamarre I was going through the solr 5.2documentation. In which they have described the Solr pagination with cursors approach. If you are using solr 5.x then probably you can use it. Otherwise you might have to update the solr version.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination naively works by retrieving all the documents up until the cut off point, throwing them away, then fetching enough documents to satisfy the number of documents requested and then returning.

If you're going to deep paging (going far into the dataset) this becomes expensive, and [the CursorMark support was implemented (see "Fetching A Large Number of Sorted Results: Cursors")](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results) to support near-instant pagination into a large set of documents.

Yonik also [has a good blog post about deep pagination in Solr](http://yonik.com/solr/paging-and-deep-paging/).